# ActiveRecord::ActsAs routing problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-routes, multi-table-inheritance

Upgrading an old Rails 3 app to Rails 4, multiple table inheritance gem has been changed due to deprecation. Now, using [ActsAs](https://github.com/krautcomputing/active_record-acts_as).

Nested routes are not working producing following error:

```
undefined method `vehicle_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f0e2778da70>:0x007f0e26725778>
```

when called:

```
  - @vehicles.each do |vehicle|
    %tr
      %td= link_to vehicle.code, vehicle
```

**Parent class:**

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  actable
end
```

**Child class:**

```
class Vehicles::Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :vehicle
end
```

**Routes.rb:**

```
namespace :vehicles do
  resources :cars, except: [:index]
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update: Rake routes**

```
vehicles          GET    /:locale/vehicles(.:format)                  vehicles#index {:locale=>/en|es/}

vehicles_cars     POST   /:locale/vehicles/cars(.:format)             vehicles/cars#create {:locale=>/en|es/}

new_vehicles_car  GET    /:locale/vehicles/cars/new(.:format)         vehicles/cars#new {:locale=>/en|es/}

edit_vehicles_car GET    /:locale/vehicles/cars/:id/edit(.:format)    vehicles/cars#edit {:locale=>/en|es/}

vehicles_car      GET    /:locale/vehicles/cars/:id(.:format)         vehicles/cars#show {:locale=>/en|es/}

                  PATCH  /:locale/vehicles/cars/:id(.:format)         vehicles/cars#update {:locale=>/en|es/}

                  PUT    /:locale/vehicles/cars/:id(.:format)         vehicles/cars#update {:locale=>/en|es/}

                  DELETE /:locale/vehicles/cars/:id(.:format)
```

Comment: What output gives you `rake routes`?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla, Updated. Thanks.

Comment: You can try with something like `%td= link_to vehicle.code, vehicles_path(vehicle, @car)` where `@car` is an intance of the car that you want to show.

Comment: 'vehicle' is the instance of the object. This vehicle could be a car, or something else.

Comment: Did you try with `%td= link_to vehicle.code, vehicles_car_path(vehicle)` ?

Comment: I have a list of generic vehicles, I can't build an specific path to a car object.

Comment: But the `vehicle` will contain what you store in the instance `@vehicles` your controller, rigth? there is where you must control what object show. That makes sense to you?